# Using json_encode to temporarily store Resources from the YouTube Data API

Tags: php, json, youtube

I've been working on a custom WordPress plugin for integrating YouTube content into a gaming blog, and in order to limit the strain on the daily API quota, I've been trying to come up with a way to store temporary cache objects which expire after 24 hours.

I created the following class to manage the data:

```
public class YouTubeDataCache {
    protected $dataObject;
    protected $expirationDate;

    __construct($dataObject) {
        $this->dataObject = $dataObject;
        $this->expirationDate = time() + 86400;
    }

    public function isExpired() {
        return $this->expirationDate < time();
    }

    public function getDataObject() {
        return $this->dataObject;
    }
}
```

And then, I call `json_encode($dataCache)` on instances of this class to generate a JSON representation of the instance that I can store in the DB.

Once I started testing this, though, I noticed two significant problems:

1. The database entries were blank despite verifyin that Google's API returned actual results.
2. calling `json_decode()` on the strings pulled *out* of the database returned fatal errors for undefined methods when I tried calling `isExpired()` on the decoded object.

My question is two-fold:

1. How can I make sure that all the necessary data elements get encoded into the JSON string?
2. How can I retain access to the object's methods after calling `json_decode()`?

Answer (score 0):

It took some time to track this down, but here is the solution that I came up with.

## How do I store all the necessary data elements in the cache?

The specifics of this will vary slightly depending on individual use-cases but the gist of it is this: `json_encode()` will only encode **public** variables.

Because my `$dataObject` and `$expirationDate` were defined as `protected`, `json_encode()` had no access to the values, and therefore encoded blank objects. Oops.

Digging a little deeper, the objects returned from the YouTube API also contained a lot of `protected` data elements, so even if I changed my class variables to `public`, I'd still encounter a similar problem trying to store things like video thumbnails.

Ultimately, I had to create my own serialization function.

Newer versions of PHP can utilize the [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) interface and define a class-specific implementation which, according to the documentation, "returns data which can be serialized by `json_encode()`"

Since I can't accurately predict what version of PHP users of this plugin will be running, I opted to just create a `toJSON()` method instead, and modified the constructor to pull specific data elements out of the `$dataObject`.

**First, the constructor/class variables:**

For my particular use-case, I'm only concerned about the ID, snippet, status and the thumbnail information. If you need additional data elements, you'll want to dig into the structure of the response object to see what your serialization function needs to manually include.

```
YouTubeDataCache {
    protected $objectId;
    protected $snippet;
    protected $status;
    protected $thumbnails = array();
    protected $expirationDate;

    __construct($dataObject = null) {
        $this->expirationDate = time() + 86400;

        if ($dataObject === null) {
            return; // I'll explain later
        }

        $this->objectId = $dataObject->getId();
        $this->snippet = $dataObject->getSnippet();
        $this->status = $dataObject->getStatus();

        $thumbs = $dataObject->getThumbnails();

        if ($thumbs->getDefault()) {
            $this->addThumbnail('default', $thumbs->getDefault());
        }
        if ($thumbs->getMedium()) {
            $this->addThumbnail('medium', $thumbs->getMedium());
        }
        if ($thumbs->getHigh()) {
            $this->addThumbnail('high', $thumbs->getHigh());
        }
        if ($thumbs->getMaxRes()) {
            $this->addThumbnail('maxRes', $thumbs->getMaxRes());
        }
    }

    public function setExpirationDate($expirationDate) {
        $this->expirationDate = $expirationDate;
    }

    public function addThumbnail($name, $data) {
        $this->thumbnails[$name] = $data;
    }

    public function getObjectId() {
        return $this->objectId;
    }

    public function setObjectId($objectId) {
        $this->objectId = $objectId;
    }

    public function getSnippet() {
        return $this->snippet;
    }

    public function setSnippet($snippet) {
        $this->snippet = $snippet;
    }

    public function getStatus() {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus($status) {
        $this->status = $status;
    }
}
```

*NOTE:* There is one caveat here. Technically, the thumbnail information is contained in the Snippet, but it's tied up in a `protected` array. Since I'll need to pull it out of that array eventually, doing it here provides a more consistent access pattern for what comes next.

**Next I added the custom serialization method**

*NOTE:* This is a class method. I just pulled it out for readability

```
public function toJSON() {
    $array = array(
        'objectId'          => $this->objectId,
        'snippet'           => $this->snippet,
        'status'            => $this->status,
        'thumbnails'        => $this->thumbnails,
        'expirationDate'    => $this->expirationDate
    );

    return json_encode($array);
}
```

With this function, I can now call `$cacheObject->toJson()` to generate an accurately encoded JSON representation of the data that I can then write to the database, which brings us to the second part of the solution.

---

## How do I retain access to the cache object's methods?

It turns out `json_decode` creates either a `stdClass` instance or an associative array (depending on how you choose to call the function). In either scenario, it doesn't have any of the methods present on the class originally used to create the JSON string, so I ultimately had to create a custom *deserialization* method as well.

I chose to make this particular function `static` so that I didn't need an instance of the cache object to use it.

```
public static function fromJSON($json) {
    $data = json_decode($json);

    $cacheObject = new YouTubeDataCache();
    /* This is why the constructor now accepts a null argument.
    I won't always have access to an API response object from
    Google, and in such cases, it's faster to just call setters
    on this class rather than jumping through hoops to create the
    Google class instance. */

    $cacheObject->setExpirationDate($data->expirationDate);
    $cacheObject->setObjectId($data->objectId);
    $cacheObject->setSnippet($data->snippet);
    $cacheObject->setStatus($data->status);

    foreach($data->thumbnails as $name => $thumbnail) {
        $cacheObject->addThumbnail($name, $thumbnail);
    }

    return $cacheObject;
}
```

## The final class definition

Just for reference purposes, here is the final class definition all in one place:

```
YouTubeDataCache {
    protected $objectId;
    protected $snippet;
    protected $status;
    protected $thumbnails = array();
    protected $expirationDate;

    __construct($dataObject = null) {
        $this->expirationDate = time() + 86400;

        if ($dataObject === null) {
            return;
        }

        $this->objectId = $dataObject->getId();
        $this->snippet = $dataObject->getSnippet();
        $this->status = $dataObject->getStatus();

        $thumbs = $dataObject->getThumbnails();

        if ($thumbs->getDefault()) {
            $this->addThumbnail('default', $thumbs->getDefault());
        }
        if ($thumbs->getMedium()) {
            $this->addThumbnail('medium', $thumbs->getMedium());
        }
        if ($thumbs->getHigh()) {
            $this->addThumbnail('high', $thumbs->getHigh());
        }
        if ($thumbs->getMaxRes()) {
            $this->addThumbnail('maxRes', $thumbs->getMaxRes());
        }
    }

    public function setExpirationDate($expirationDate) {
        $this->expirationDate = $expirationDate;
    }

    public function addThumbnail($name, $data) {
        $this->thumbnails[$name] = $data;
    }

    public function getObjectId() {
        return $this->objectId;
    }

    public function setObjectId($objectId) {
        $this->objectId = $objectId;
    }

    public function getSnippet() {
        return $this->snippet;
    }

    public function setSnippet($snippet) {
        $this->snippet = $snippet;
    }

    public function getStatus() {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus($status) {
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    public function toJSON() {
        $array = array(
            'objectId'          => $this->objectId,
            'snippet'           => $this->snippet,
            'status'            => $this->status,
            'thumbnails'        => $this->thumbnails,
            'expirationDate'    => $this->expirationDate
        );

        return json_encode($array);
    }

    public static function fromJSON($json) {
        $data = json_decode($json);

        $cacheObject = new YouTubeDataCache();

        $cacheObject->setExpirationDate($data->expirationDate);
        $cacheObject->setObjectId($data->objectId);
        $cacheObject->setSnippet($data->snippet);
        $cacheObject->setStatus($data->status);

        foreach($data->thumbnails as $name => $thumbnail) {
            $cacheObject->addThumbnail($name, $thumbnail);
        }

        return $cacheObject;
    }
}
```